# Low quality photo to look good

Tags: photo-editing, image-quality

As I have many pictures in which I have taken from my mobile phone whose picture quality comes good but not good as DSLRs or any HD quality camera.

To look my photo or the main object in picture look HD or attractive towards others and not feel them bad by the looking at the poor quality of photo.

So can any one help me out to solve my problem?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can achieve your solution by just following the 4 basic steps,

1. Find something you want to take a picture of make sure your hands are steady and then take the picture.
2. Now you must take the picture off of the camera and put it on a computer. Hopefully you know how to do this, or else there is not much that I will be able to do for you.
3. This step is pretty self-explanatory. I would recommend GIMP, because this has the blur function.
4. Now use the blur function to make everything around your main object blurry. This make the main focus the object, not the quality of the picture. This will make your photos much more high-quality looking and will make you feel like a professional photographer as well.